# Combo wireless keyboard+mouse, Mouse is not working

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse

I bought this yesterday http://www.cdrking.com/?mod=products&type=view&sid=21638&main=167#.VdhuKN9_c8o. It's a mouse and keyboard with one usb receiver. The keyboard is working perfectly but not the mouse. You can see the product's information in the link. But I think this is the important info for the Mouse

```
- 2.4GHz operating frequency
- Free Switch CPI
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

After running `lsusb` with the receiver plugin. I got this.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1d57:fa60 Xenta // Missing when receiver is not plugged in
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b35d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 17ef:6020 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The difference when the receiver is not plugin is the **Xenta** Bus

I tried doing this, doesn't help.

```
sudo modprobe -rv psmouse
sudo modprobe -v psmouse
```

**Edit 1**

```
> xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver                       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver                       id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Please let me know how can I give you more details.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the output of xinput

Answer (score 1):

This was the same case with me. I'd bought a combo keyboard and mouse, just like yours with a usb receiver. The first time I plugged it in, it was not working, the whole set.

Yet, your case looks a little bit different to me. Your keyboard is working but mouse is not. So, first, check if there is any hardware/manufacturing problem with the device. This is pretty common. It could be anywhere from battery issues to receiver problem.

Next, here are some more things you can do:-

- Check if there is any need of drivers. Or, you could use the software and updates app in Ubuntu to install drivers for 3rd party.
- Try plugging the device to another machine (windows or linux) . If it also does not respond, consider getting it replaced, it might be faulty.
- Try to run a linux distro live (ubuntu or another one), and then check if the mouse works. This happened once. My mouse was not working with Opensuse, but on trying it with Fedora live, it worked seamlessly.

This is all I have as far the case of the mouse is concerned. I hope it helps you !

Answer (score 1):

I have a wireless mouse with usb dongle (cdrking). Works fine when plugged to a 32 bit peppermint linux.

On my 64 bit 14.04 ubuntu it wouldn't work when plugged in directly to a USB3.0 port on my laptop. But, it works when plugged through a 4-port usb2.0 hub extension. This is just a workaround instead of having to buy a new mouse.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-plugin.cursor KEY=active VALUE=true
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Not yet, I'll try this later when I get home. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I'm getting this error

**No such schema 'org.settings.gnome-plugin.cursor'**

Comment: Try whit KEY=s.cusor

Comment: doesn't have any output and doesn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: Try KEY=cursor VALUE=false

Comment: No output and doesn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: Try then this KEY=active VALUE=false

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but nothing happened with the last command.